# How do I detect if a browser tab is currently visible and rendering using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm animating some image presentation using

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $('.img').css('someprop', randomValue()); 
}, 2000);
```

..where .img has css transitions enabled, hence animation.

When i go over to another tab for a few minutes and come back to this tab, the animations go crazy for 5-6 seconds and catch up with everything at once.

Is there a way for me to stop the accumulation of undisplayed animations while the tab is not visible? What's the right approach to solve this? I understand the browser stops the animations while a window is not rendering, for performance reasons, but is there a way for me to tell it not to try to catch up with everything it "missed out on" ?

Answer (score 1):

`window.requestAnimationFrame` does exactly what you want, only animating/running when the tab is "active" (visible).

See the [MDN page on requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) for more details.

Example code by Paul Irish, posted here for posterity ([here's a link to his explanation page](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/))

```
// requestAnim shim layer by Paul Irish
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
              function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();


// example code from mr doob : http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/requestanimationframe/

var canvas, context, toggle;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 512;

    context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

    document.body.appendChild( canvas );

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame( animate );
    draw();

}

function draw() {

    var time = new Date().getTime() * 0.002;
    var x = Math.sin( time ) * 192 + 256;
    var y = Math.cos( time * 0.9 ) * 192 + 256;
    toggle = !toggle;

    context.fillStyle = toggle ? 'rgb(200,200,20)' :  'rgb(20,20,200)';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc( x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

}
```